# SvelteKit on AWS Amplify: Error 500: Internal Error

Tags: svelte, aws-amplify, sveltekit

i recently deployed my SvelteKit app on AWS Amplify. I use the "@sveltejs/adapter-static" and set `export const prerender = true;` in my root +layout.ts file. Everything works except the pages where i have to set `export const prerender = false;`. For example on my /login page. Svelte return a 500 and an error: *SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*. I am still new to SvelteKit and frontend technologies like Svelte.

I am pretty sure i'm just doing something wrong with the prerender/static logic.

svelte.config.js:

```
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            fallback: 'index.html'
        }),
        prerender: {
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

/routes/+layout.ts

```
export const prerender = true;
export const ssr = true;
```

/routes/login/+page.server.ts:

```
import { sha512 } from "../../utils/sha512";
import {fail, redirect} from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { JWT_ACCESS_SECRET } from '$env/static/private'
import { loading } from '$lib/loading'

export const load: PageServerLoad = (event) => {
    const user = event.locals.user;

    if (user) {
        throw redirect(302, '/profile');
    }
};

export const actions = {
    default: async (event: {
            request: { formData: () => any; }; cookies: {
                set: (arg0: string, arg1: string, arg2: {
                    httpOnly: boolean; path: string; secure: boolean; sameSite: string; maxAge: number; // 1 day
                }) => void;
            };
        }) => {
        loading.set(true);
        const data = await event.request.formData();
        const email = data.get('email');
        const password = await sha512(data.get('password'));

        if (!email) {
            return fail(400, { email, missing: true });
        }

        const res = await POST('auth/login', JSON.stringify({email: email, p: password}));

        if (!res['is_logged_in']) {
            return fail(400, { email, incorrect: true });
        }

        const jwtUser = {
            id: res.id,
            email: res.email
        };

        const token = jwt.sign(jwtUser, JWT_ACCESS_SECRET, {
            expiresIn: '1d'
        });

        event.cookies.set('AuthorizationToken', `Bearer ${token}`, {
            httpOnly: true,
            path: '/',
            secure: true,
            sameSite: 'strict',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 // 1 day
        });

        loading.set(false);

        throw redirect(302, '/profile');
    }
};

export const prerender = false;
```